# How to "cheat" synthesis to keep an unused signal without using special compile directives?

Tags: vhdl

In relation to a work-around for a tool issue, it is required to "cheat" synthesis and optimization to keep an unused signal, but the synthesis appears to be pretty "smart" at detecting and removing actually unused signals.  For example, the code below is optimized away, since the `unused_*` signal are not used elsewhere:

```
unused_1 <= ...;  -- Some value assigned elsewhere
process (clk_i) is
begin
  if rising_edge(clk_i) then
    unused_2 <= unused_1 and unused_2;
  end if;
end process;
```

Usually there is tool support for attributes like "keep", but that does not work with the tool version.  Having an unused chip output is neither desirable.

So, is there some general way to "cheat" synthesis and optimization to not optimized a signal away, even through the signal is effectively unused?

Comment: Which toolchain do you use? If you are using Xilinx ISE: Attache the attribute `KEEP` to the signal and/or disable hierarchy flattening (keep hierarchy). Tools usually don't optimize primitives. If you use a D-FF instead of rising_edge(...) it will preserve the flip flip.

Comment: Actually using Lattice Diamond tool, but question is if a general approach exists.

Answer (score 1):

Make the signal an output.
You may need to connect it all way to the top level output (pin) in a hierarchical design.

Comment: That is the straight forward way, but, as I wrote in the question, not desirable.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to generate an internal constant '1' value after 2 cycles (`one` in code below), and this constant '1' value can then be ORed on the unused signal (`one or unused_1`), and the resulting value can then be ANDed on some other expression without effect since constant '1' (`used_1 and (one or unused_1)`).  The `used_as_1` when then experience an additional delay, but with same logical value.

A way to generate and internal constant '1' for both Altera, Lattice, and Xilinx is:

```
architecture syn of mdl is

  signal cnt : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0) := "00";
  signal one : std_logic;

  signal unused_1 : std_logic;

  signal used_1    : std_logic;  -- Some used signal
  signal used_as_1 : std_logic;  -- Same value as used_1, but merged unused_1 to keep

begin

  -- Trivial '1' made in one without removal by optimization
  process (clk_i) is
  begin
    if rising_edge(clk_i) then
      one <= cnt(0) or cnt(1);
      if unsigned(cnt) = 3 then
        cnt <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(cnt) + 2);
      else
        cnt <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(cnt) + 1);
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;

  -- Merge unused with used code to avoid removal by synthesis
  used_as_1 <= used_1 and (one or unused_1);

  ... actual code

end architecture;
```

The current versions of these tools do not identify this as being a constant 1, thus do not remove the circuit.

Comment: Do you have a tie in between this and your original question?  Where did unused_1 go?

Comment: @JimLewis: Updated the code with example of how to use the `one` value to cheat synthesis to keep `unused_1` without without affecting used signals (except for first 2 cycles).